# Group data from 3 tables and sort by week ending date

Tags: sql, date

Here is the problem I am stuck on.

I have three tables which log the dates and locations customers visit my sales centers. One table is the initial visit, the second is a able for repeat visits, of which there could be many and the third is a deposit table which stores the data related to when people leave a deposit and on which job they left the deposit.

So I need to sort all do this data by the week ending date, which I do have working on one table at a time. So for example, anyone who visited my sales center on March 3 would be counted in as traffic for the week ending march 9.

Now I would like to query the data so that I call pull the dates from the other two tables as well and have them sort by week ending along with the other data.

So my final output would look like this:

```
Week ending | initial visit | bback | deposit

3/9/2014           9            3        0
3/16/2104.         12.          0.       1
```

My tables structure looks like this:

```
Salescenter_clientinfo
  Initial_visit (date)
  Community

Customer_bback
   Bback_date
   Bback_community

Customer Deposit 
   Deposit_date
   Doposit_community
```

All of these tables also have a field which is the customer_id which links them all.

As stated earlier, I do have the sql working which gets the job done using one table but how do I accomplish this on multiple tables?

I forgot to mention, I run this sql from an excel pivot table against an MSSql database.  I am using excel to do the pivot and be the final report.

Any help in very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: What query do you use to get the end of the week in a single table?

Comment: Set Datefirst 1;
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT DATEPART(year, initial_visit) AS YEAR, DATEPART(ww, initial_visit) AS Week, DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, initial_visit), initial_visit) 
                      AS WeekEnding, community_name, COUNT(initial_visit) AS totalvisits, last_name, initial_visit, customer_status
FROM         dbo.ViewCountVisitsByDayByCommunity
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, initial_visit), DATEPART(ww, initial_visit), initial_visit, community_name, last_name, initial_visit, customer_status

ORDER BY YEAR, Week, WeekEnding

Comment: What happens when you inner join the 3 tables?

Comment: I just get all those records, from each table, where there is also an entry in the bback table.

Comment: Take a [look at this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03ae0/6) and tell me what i'm missing

Comment: It did not pull back any data, Now i changed the inner joins to left joins and that did pull back the data. Tried this both in the sql & excel with the same results. When data does pull back, the count of the bback's are still grouped in with the week ending on the initial visit, not the week ending that corresponds to when the bback visit occurred.

Comment: I think its clear you are looking for more than what your question states.  Why dont you update the schema of that sql fiddle and post what the results of it SHOULD be.

Comment: If you want to just update this question, and post a comment here so i'm notified, i'll be happy to look into it again.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your original question correctly, you're trying to track everything that happened at your center, in each category, during a specific week.  So if a customer's initial visit was during week 1, and he/she came back during week 2, those two items would fall under different weeks.

Based on that assumption, the linkage on Customer_ID is actually a bit of a red herring: you want data aggregated by week, and don't care if it all reflects the same customer's initial visit.

If so, then the following SQL might do what you are looking for:

```
Set Datefirst 1; 

SELECT 
  ISNULL(vc.WeekEnding, ISNULL(b.WeekEnding, d.WeekEnding)) WeekEnding,
  vc.InitialVisit,
  b.BBack,
  d.Deposit
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, initial_visit), initial_visit) AS WeekEnding,
      COUNT(initial_visit) AS InitialVisit
    FROM dbo.SalesCenter_clientinfo 
    GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, initial_visit), initial_visit)
  ) vc
   FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, Bback_date), Bback_date) AS WeekEnding,
      COUNT(Bback_date) AS BBack
    FROM dbo.Customer_bback 
    GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, Bback_date), Bback_date)
  ) b ON 
    vc.WeekEnding = b.WeekEnding
   FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, Deposit_date), Deposit_date) AS WeekEnding,
      COUNT(Deposit_date) AS Deposit
    FROM dbo.Customer_deposit 
    GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 7 - DATEPART(DW, Deposit_date), Deposit_date)
  ) d ON 
    vc.WeekEnding = d.WeekEnding
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03ae0/10)